How to get dynamic power with Cadence tools?
I assume that this question must be answered in some place. However, I cannot find a clear answer.
I have a Verilog design. I have been using Genus from Cadence to obtain area resource results, and I could obtain static power. However, I want to get dynamic power results. While searching online, I came up with Virtuoso, as the major search funds mention it. However, I realize that it is for creating libraries...
Can someone give me some insights on this? Major of Cadence's resources are caped.

more context what are you talking about?

I don't know what info is missing (probably because I still need more knowledge). I have a code in Verilog and a test bench, and I want to obtain the dynamic power, but I cannot find which tool (program) I should use.

Genus report_power generates dynamic power results too (depending on the tool version). To obtain a better estimate of dynamic power the switching activity of the design needs to be read into Genus. Switching activity files (TCF/SAIF) can be generated from Incisive/Xcelium simulator using for eg. dumptcf and read into Genus using the readtcf command.
